# Erase element from list of type struct

Tags: c++, pointers

This is the declaration of my list: `list<Message*> g_messages;`

where `Message` is a `struct`.

I want to delete a certain position of the list (a Message). If it was a vector, I would do it like this:

`//delete g_messages[id];`

with lists .erase() must be used, but I don't know how.

`g_messages.erase(id);` doesn't work. It was suggested to use an iterator, but how do I link the `const int` id and the iterator?

Comment: `list` does not provide random access. You have to use an `iterator` to access the elements

Comment: `delete g_messages[id];` does ***not*** remove the item from the vector!

Comment: How are you getting this `id` in the first place? A good start would be to use `list<Message>`, or if you really need a pointer, then `list<unique_ptr<Message>>`

Comment: Sounds like `list` was the wrong choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it with lists, you have to iterate through all of them, since they r doubly-linked lists (each element contains a pointer to the previous and next element).

```
// loop through all the elements
for (auto& it = g_messages.begin(); it != g_messages.end(); it++)
{
    if ((*it)->id == input_id)
    {
        delete *it;
        g_messages.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use std::find_if from `<algorithm>` which takes a predicate

```
auto it = std::find_if(g_messages.begin(), g_messages.end(), [input_id](Message* p){ return (p->id == input_id); });

if (it != g_messages.end())
{
    delete *it;
    g_messages.erase(it);
}
```

EDIT: as requested by the OP (delete by it's position relative to start)

```
// loop through all the elements
int i = -1;
for (auto& it = g_messages.begin(); it != g_messages.end(); it++)
{
    if (++i == input_position)
    {
        delete *it;
        g_messages.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

OR

```
auto it = g_messages.begin();

if (input_position < g_messages.size())
{
    std::advance(it, input_position);
    g_messages.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Nice code dump. How about an explanation. Might also want to fix that bug you have as well.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sometimes loops that are so small really self explanatory... but I've added some info now ;D

Comment: Ha! You updated your answer to include the exact code that I was typing.

Comment: This isn't one of those times. Stack Overflow is a community site so this answer isn't just for the person posting the question.

Comment: @José It looks good but it says that `Message` has no member `id`

Comment: I had no idea what your field to identify such structure was named, so I named it id. if ((*it)->id == id)   (you need to change the ((*it)->id to (*it)->yourfieldname. I've updated my answer check it out.

Comment: @José okay I see what you mean but what I want to delete is the whole message in the "position" id

Comment: Updated my answer again, hopefully it's what you want.

Comment: Okay, it works! Thank you so much! If I may bother you one more time... next I am supposed to delete another position: `g_messages.erase(g_messages.begin() + id);` There is an error because, to my understanding, g_messages.begin() is an iterator and id, on the other hand, is an int. Any idea how to solve this? Thank you again :)

Comment: There's no + operator for list<>::iterators (only ++). That's why you need a function that wraps the code I gave you and call it every time you want to delete an item. Something like delete_from_list(std::list<Message*> &list, int input_position) and has my code inside of it. Or you could use templates to accept lists of any type. You can call it like: delete_from_list(g_messages, input_position);

Answer (score 1):

To erase an element in a [`list<Message*>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) you have to do three things:

- get an iterator that points to the element you want to get rid of.  Unfortunately [list iterators are bidirectional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/):  you can go to the start or the end of the list and move one single step foarward/backward at a time.
- delete the object you point to (by the way, it would be safer to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers here:  you could then skip this additional step and be sure that you're not leaking memory)
- [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) the element of the list

Here how to do it:

```
auto it = g_messages.begin();   // iterator to start at begin of list 
it++;it++;              // move two steps forward (i.e. 2x  1 step)
delete *it;             // delete the allocated object you point to 
g_messages.erase(it);   // erase the elemnt in the list.
```

Here a quick [live demo](http://ideone.com/wej1t9) using smart pointers.